# HERE Traffic Incident API Call Not Displaying Accidents

Tags: here-api, traffic

I am using a HERE API call to request traffic incident data from a particular start time. Whenever I include the "type" key and specify "Accident" as the value, no response is returned. However, switching the value to "Construction" does provide a response.

Does anyone have information on how to make the API call return accident data specifically?

Here is the exact call I am using:

```
https://traffic.api.here.com/traffic/6.3/incidents.json?app_id={{app_id}}&app_code={{app_code}}&startTime=2017-01-01T00:00:00-05:00&type=Accident&bbox=52.5233,13.4035;52.5181,13.4159
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no data returned as there are no “Accident” type incidents in that location. This can be seen when skipping the “type” parameter:

```
https://traffic.api.here.com/traffic/6.3/incidents.xml?app_id=APP_ID&app_code=APP_CODE&startTime=2017-01-01T00:00:00-05:00&bbox=52.5233,13.4035;52.5181,13.4159
```

Traffic Data is dynamic data. Accident can be located somewhere and disappear in a matter of minutes. We recommend to use wego.here.com to locate an accident, or Bing maps (they are all using our services and traffic data).
We were able to find one in Germany right now (should be there until 13:34 German time):

```
https://traffic.api.here.com/traffic/6.3/incidents.xml?app_id=app_id&app_code=app_code&startTime=2017-01-01T00:00:00-05:00&prox=51.52427,11.85887,15&type=Accident
```

Hope this helps! Happy Coding!

Comment: Any way to get historical accidents?

Comment: Currently we don't show individual historical information.